# excel address as lookup array

Tags: excel, indexing, match

first of all, thank you in advance. 
the problem I am facing is I have two different values I need to combine when I lookup against a different table, however I do not know which columns those two combinations will be, and they can be different per row. hopefully, the example will help

**look up table**

```
ID | Benefit | Option | Tier | Benefit | Option | Tier
123| 1       | 1      | 3    | 2       | 7      |3
456| 2       |3       |1     |1        |3      |2
```

**current table**

```
ID  | Benefit |
123 | 1
123 | 2
456 | 1
456 | 2
```

[image: excel screenshot]

the example i am giving there is only two posibility it can be in but my actual program is it could be in maybe 20 different location. the one positive i have is that it will always be under the benefit column, so what i was thinking is concat benefit & 04 and using the index match. i would like to dynamically concat based on the row my lookup is on 
here is what i got so far but its not working

=INDEX(T3:X4,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0),MATCH($O$3&O4,T2:X2&ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($S$3:$S$4,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0))),20):ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($S$3:$S$4,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0))),24),0))

where 
ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($S$3:$S$4,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0))),20) does return T3 
and ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($S$3:$S$4,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0))),24) returns x3
so i was hoping it would combine benefit&1 and it would see its a match on t 3

Comment: why not you try like something like =if(a1+a2=t3,true,false)

Comment: I think you are going to need to restructure your data in order to do this in pure Excel.  Currently, you need two separate lookups to find a value.

Comment: ADDRESS function returns a text result - to convert that to an excel friendly cell reference you would need INDIRECT function.....but there are probably simpler/better approaches, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find a formula to put in P4 to P7 ?

```
=INDEX($S$2:$X$4,MATCH(N4,$S$2:$S$4,0),SUMPRODUCT(($S$2:$X$2="wtwben")*(OFFSET($S$2:$X$2,MATCH(N4,$S$3:$S$4,0),0)=O4)*(COLUMN($S$2:$X$2)-COLUMN($S$2)+1))+1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this returned exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the values to return are always numeric and there is only one match for each ID/Benefit combination (as it appears in your sample) then you can get the Option value with this formula in `P4` copied down

`=SUMPRODUCT((S$3:S$4=N4)*(T$2:W$2="Benefit")*(T$3:W$4=O4),U$3:X$4)`

[assumes the headers are per the first table shown in your question, i.e. where `T2` value is "Benefit"]

Notice how the ranges change

....or to return text values.....or if the ID/Benefit combination repeats this will give you the "first" match, where "first" means by row.

`=INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(U$3:X$4)*1000+COLUMN(U$3:X$4))/(S$3:S$4=N4)/(T$2:W$2="Benefit")/(T$3:W$4=O4),1),"R0C000"),FALSE)`